# I am trying to pull data from 2 tables and for some items there is not data in one of the tables

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

I am creating a report that pulls data from multiple tables.  The report is to track rather a unit pass or failed and if it failed, why it failed.  The why it is a different table then if.  If the unit pass there will be no data in the table for why it failed.  Because of this any thing that pass will not show in the report.  We need to report to show everything rather it passed or failed.  If I remove the fields from the table that show why it failed it show all units like I want but it doesn't show why a unit failed.

Comment: If you don´t upload your code  and your DB structure it is imposible to help you

Comment: *I have tried that and it didn't work. I miss spoke earlier. There are 3 tables not 2. data in one table never changes.* -- then please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] showing your current schema and what you have tried that does not work.  See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You need to use left (or right) join. it will include all the records from one table even if there is no corresponding record in the other

Comment: I have tried that and it didn't work.  I miss spoke earlier.  There are 3 tables not 2.  data in one table never changes.